# Minecraft Bukkit Plugin: My minigame teleporter not working

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to make a minigames, so when I want players automatically to teleport after countdown, but nobody teleports, I made a command to start the game and teleport (that works), so here is my code (this is Icelandic server so variables names is on icelandic and some stuff):

onEnable in main class:

```
    public void onEnable() {
    stada.setjaStodu(stada.Lobby);
    nidurtalning.keyra = true;
    new Thread(new nidurtalning()).start();
    registerEvt();
    getCmd();
    for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        p.teleport(playerJoin.wait);
        p.setGameMode(GameMode.ADVENTURE);
    }

}
```

When countdown variable is 0 (klukka):

```
if(klukka == 0){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Bukkit.shutdown();
                }
                for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){

                    p.playSound(p.getLocation(), "random.levelup", 100.0F, 1F);
                    byrja.teleportToGame(p);
                }

                stada.setjaStodu(stada.Leikur);
                chat.tilkynna("Og þið megið byrja!", false);

                keyra = false;
            }
```

And the teleport class:

```
public class byrja {


public static void teleportToGame(Player p){
    World war = Bukkit.getWorld("Empty");
    Location leikur = new Location(war, -416, 253, 175);
    p.teleport(leikur);
}
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly the default `UncaughtExceptionHandler` for threads can be `null`, which would mean exceptions would not print. My guess is `Bukkit.getWorld("Empty")` is returning null, and you're getting an NPE when `Location` attempts to use `war` in order to teleport the player.

The `Thread` really isn't needed here, Bukkit has its own scheduler you can use (`Bukkit#getScheduler`)

Answer (score 0):

Use **NEVER**

```
Thread.sleep();
```

Since it will pause the whole thread!
Even if you are using an *asnc scheduler* its still not good! (It will cost unnecessary resources)

Instead use a **RunTaskLater** Scheduler

However... Are u sure that the world **Empty** exists?`

All in all the function should work however!

Something like this:

```
protected void endCountdown(int klukka) {
    if (klukka == 0) {
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(pl, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().stream().forEach(all -> {
                    all.playSound(all.getLocation(), Sound.LEVEL_UP, 100, 1);
                    teleportToGame(all);
                });
                // DO MORE STUFF IF NEEDED
            }
        }, 10);
    }
}

private void teleportToGame(Player p) {
    World war = Bukkit.getWorld("Empty");
    Location loc = new Location(war, -416, 253, 175);
    p.teleport(loc);
}
```